# When I pull down to refresh on my UIScrollView it requires me to pull down to the middle of the screen

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview, refresh

I have a function: `didPullToRefresh()`. In order to set this function into motion, I have to pull my `UIScrollView` all the way to the middle of the screen. Is there a way I can refresh the data I want to refresh by only pulling the screen down 50 pixels? Thanks?

Here is the code I am currently running:

```
var refreshControl: UIRefreshControl!
override func viewDidLoad()  {
   super.viewDidLoad()

   scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
   scrollView.bounces  = true
   refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
   refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didPullToRefresh), for: .valueChanged)
   self.scrollView.addSubview(refreshControl)
 }

@objc func didPullToRefresh() {

 print("Refersh")

 // For End refrshing
refreshControl?.endRefreshing()  


 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't add target to Refresh control. Just addSubView it to scrollview. In viewDidLoad:

```
scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
scrollView.bounces  = true
scrollView.delegate = self

refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
self.scrollView.addSubview(refreshControl)
```

Set scrollview delegate to self. And implement following scrollview delegate method:

```
func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
    if scrollView.contentOffset.y <= -50 {
        refreshControl.beginRefreshing()
        print("Start Refresh Service")
    }
}
```

Write "refreshControl?.endRefreshing()" on refresh service finish.

Comment: is there a way to do this, but to delay the bouncing while it loads?

Comment: Like this? :: DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {
      // Write your code here.
    }

Comment: can you edit the code above showing where that would go?

Comment: FYI, scrollView now has the `refreshControl` property.
Please use that when wanting a `refreshControl` on a UIScrollView.